# How to get View size in meters?

Tags: android, view

There is a way to convert view's float coordinates to length in meters or another real unit?

I have a surfaceview that displays the motion of some real body and I want to display the scale of the animation, so I have to get the conversion from coordinates or sizes of the view to meters...

Comment: I think you mean "in metric system". Also consider why you want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be in millimeters?

```
int width= view.getMeasuredWidth(); // will be in px
float mm = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, width, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

also check out other `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_` (maybe inches?)

Comment: Thanks! The coordinates of a surfaceview are in pixel? So I can get millimeters of a pixel through TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); ?

Comment: indeed, result is a float, with one pixel it will be very small number (after coma). try with 100 px. almost every sizes etc. which you can obtain from code are in px, so probably cords of `SurfaceView` also